# Formula Appliance as SR

Tags: sql, postgresql

My Data is like this

```
wavelength    reflectance
341.6         2.48
343.6         2.58
344.7         2.37
346.3         2.32
347.9         2.29
349.5         2.36
351.1         2.23
352.6         2.24
354.2         2.25
355.8         2.29
357.4         2.28
358.9         2.23
```

I want to use the formula

- Select the reflectance between the wavelength 340-345 and add the
  reflectance values then the added value as r
- Select the reflectance between the wavelength 350-355 and add the
  reflectance values then the added value as i

Formula is

- r/i
- Output of r/i named as tera

Expected Output

```
tera
1.105655
```

How i should do this in PostgreSQL? I am a beginner of PostgreSQL, if anyone knows tell me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Formula Appliance on Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779545/formula-appliance-on-data)

Comment: Please don't post the exact same question again

Comment: It is different formula but related to that one...

Comment: You can merge two question into a single one. Include your previous formula in this one and delete the previous question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT (SUM(r)/SUM(i)) AS tera FROM
((SELECT SUM(reflectance) AS r, 0 AS i FROM table WHERE wavelength BETWEEN 340 AND 345)
UNION
(SELECT 0 AS r, SUM(reflectance) AS i FROM table WHERE wavelength BETWEEN 350 AND 355))
AS total
```